# R - Subsetting data by Hour:Minute

Tags: r, date, time, subset

In my dataframe I have a column called "TIMESTAMP" in a dataframe called BG.data

```
 TIMESTAMP                  
          14/04/2014 14:30      
          14/04/2014 14:45              
          14/04/2014 15:15      
          14/04/2014 15:30      
          14/04/2014 15:45              
          14/04/2014 16:00      
          14/04/2014 16:15  

class(BG.data$TIMESTAMP)
[1] "factor"
```

Okay now I want to make a column with just the hour and minute in it, so I can subset the data just based on this information. This is the code that I tried to do so.

```
BG.data$Hour <- as.POSIXct(BG.data$TIMESTAMP, format="%H:%M")
```

Which just returned a column of NA's

Why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returned NAs because you didn't take into account the date that is also present in each entry. Coercing to character with `as.character()` is not necessary as it does it within the function:

```
BG.data$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(BG.data$TIMESTAMP, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Then to extract only the hour and minute part of the `POSIXct` object:

```
BG.data$HOUR <-format(BG.data$TIMESTAMP, format="%H:%M")
```